# Detecting when clicking anywhere outside of element when the clicked element has been removed from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I have a notifications dropdown menu that should be closed when you click anywhere outside of it. The following code was working great until I ran into a new situation:

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var target = e.target;

    if (!$(target).is('.notification-area') && !$(target).parents().is('.notification-area')) {
        $('.notification-area .flyout').removeClass('flyout-show');
    }
});
```

However (and I'm using Backbone if that's relevant), some elements cause part of the menu to re-render. That is to say: remove and rebuild a part of the DOM.

Obviously you can't tell where an element is within the DOM if it's already been removed. So now, if there's a click that causes part of that view to re-render then that bit of code that checks the `parents()` of the element returns no parents.

Then I thought I might be able to solve it by checking if the length of `parents()` is greater than 0.

```
...
if (!$(target).is('.notification-area') 
    && !$(target).parents().is('.notification-area')
    && $(target).parents().length > 0)
...
```

And this works but I wonder what side effects it could have. Is this the best way to do this?

Comment: How is the element clicked if it has been removed from the DOM? Is it removed in another event listener? Do you use `.click()` on a removed element?

Comment: If I can understand it correct, then the click event causes the part to re-render before the check you posted in the code happens. 
Is it possible to perform the check before the re-render ?

Answer (score 1):

Hope I understood your question correct. You want some simple way of not shutting the notification area if clicked upon it. But close it when clicked on body?

One way to do these kind of things is somewhat like this.

```
mouseOverArea = false; // This will be globally set, right away

$('.notification-area').mouseenter(function(){
    mouseOverArea = true;
}).mouseleave(function(){
    mouseOverArea = false;
});
```

And then when you click on body or whatever, you simply check if mouseOverArea == false... If so, close the notification box, otherwise return false, e.preventDefault(); or whatever fits your coding.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify this using `closest()` since it includes both the target and ancestors.

It turns :

```
!$(target).is('.notification-area') && !$(target).parents().is('.notification-area')
```

Into a simpler to read:

```
!$(target).closest('.notification-area').length
```

reference: [closest() docs](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)